# can i improve jqBootstrapValidation performance?

Tags: jquery, performance, forms, validation, twitter-bootstrap

i use jqBootstrapValidation to validate a large form, minimum 80 input fields, but it lags when i try to click in the input, anyone know how can i improve it? or do you know another validation plugin good enough?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but don't use a large form. Split it into smaller sections and validate each section before proceeding. A form with a minimum of 80 input fields would result in a pretty bad UX.

Comment: thanks by your answer, but i need it that way, it looks like i would have to change for the jquery.validation plugin.